# SQL Collision with 2 values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem.
I have a database for IT documentation
where I work a lot with primary keys.
Here the DomainID and the AccountID is my problem.

Example:
Company_Fritz - 'AccountID: 3' 'DomainID: 2

Company_Meier - 'AccountID: 4' 'DomainID: 3

Because the primary key always gets the AccountID I have problems because I use the DomainID on the side.
Example: I get for 'AccountID: 3' the data from the 'DomainID: 3'.
although 'DomainID: 3' belongs to 'AccountID: 4'.

*sorry for my english i have been studying for 2 months*

**This is my SQL Code for the AccountID**

`select * from tDomains where AccountID = {PrimaryKey}`

**and this for the list of ip addresses i want**

```sql
SELECT tNetworkIPAddress.IPAddress,
       tHosts.HostName,
       tHosts.HostTypeID,
       tHosts.HostID,
       (SELECT TypeText
        FROM tHostTypeText
        WHERE tHostTypeText.TypeID = tHosts.HostTypeID
          AND tHostTypeText.LanguageID = {LanguageID}) AS HostType
FROM tNetworkAdapter,
     tNetworkAdapterConfiguration,
     tNetworkIPAddress,
     tDocu,
     tHosts
WHERE tHosts.HostID = tDocu.HostID
  AND tDocu.DocuID = tNetworkAdapter.DocuID
  AND tNetworkAdapter.AdapterID = tNetworkAdapterConfiguration.AdapterID
  AND tNetworkAdapterConfiguration.NetConfigurationID = tNetworkIPAddress.NetConfigurationID
  AND tDocu.Archiv = 0
  AND tHosts.DomainID = {PrimaryKey}
UNION
SELECT tDocuSNMP.IPAddress,
       tHosts.HostName,
       tHosts.HostTypeID,
       tHosts.HostID,
       (SELECT TypeText
        FROM tHostTypeText
        WHERE tHostTypeText.TypeID = tHosts.HostTypeID
          AND tHostTypeText.LanguageID = {LanguageID}) AS HostType
FROM tDocuSNMP,
     tDocu,
     tHosts
WHERE tDocu.DocuID = tDocuSNMP.DocuID
  AND tDocu.HostID = tHosts.HostID
  AND tHosts.DomainID = {PrimaryKey}
UNION
SELECT tDocuCIFS.IPAddress,
       tHosts.HostName,
       tHosts.HostTypeID,
       tHosts.HostID,
       (SELECT TypeText
        FROM tHostTypeText
        WHERE tHostTypeText.TypeID = tHosts.HostTypeID
          AND tHostTypeText.LanguageID = {LanguageID}) AS HostType
FROM tDocuCIFS,
     tDocu,
     tHosts
WHERE tDocu.DocuID = tDocuCIFS.DocuID
  AND tDocu.HostID = tHosts.HostID
  AND tHosts.DomainID = {PrimaryKey}
UNION
SELECT IPOnline AS IPAddress,
       tHosts.HostName,
       tHosts.HostTypeID,
       tHosts.HostID,
       (SELECT TypeText
        FROM tHostTypeText
        WHERE tHostTypeText.TypeID = tHosts.HostTypeID
          AND tHostTypeText.LanguageID = {LanguageID}) AS HostType
FROM tHosts
WHERE tHosts.DomainID = {PrimaryKey}
  AND HostTypeID = 5
--and tHosts.IpOnline = @IPAddress
UNION
SELECT tSnmpAdapter.IpAddress,
       tHosts.HostName,
       tHosts.HostTypeID,
       tHosts.HostID,
       (SELECT TypeText
        FROM tHostTypeText
        WHERE tHostTypeText.TypeID = tHosts.HostTypeID
          AND tHostTypeText.LanguageID = {LanguageID}) AS HostType
FROM tDocu,
     tHosts,
     tSnmpAdapter
WHERE tHosts.DomainID = {PrimaryKey}
  AND tDocu.HostID = tHosts.HostID
  AND tHosts.IsUserDef = 1
  AND tDocu.DocuID = tSnmpAdapter.DocuID
  AND tDocu.Archiv = 0;
```

Comment: What is your question then? What are you asking, what about what you have isn't working?

Comment: EVOLVE - no one should be using [old-style joins via where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: What does things like `tHosts.DomainID = {PrimaryKey}` mean as well? Braces aren't valid T-SQL Identifiers and it doesn't look like they are supposed to represent variables, considering you have them in the comments (such as `--and tHosts.IpOnline = @IPAddress`).

Comment: What's wrong with a `JOIN`? As @SMor said, you should be using an explicit `JOIN` too; they were introduced 28 years ago now.

Comment: The Braces isn't valid in standard sql tools but in "Docusnap"  its valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * From tDomains where AccountID = {PrimaryKey}
select * From tAccounts where AccountID = {PrimaryKey}
select * From tHosts where DomainID in (select domainID from tDomains where AccountID = {PrimaryKey})
```